# use :focus as a :hover replacement for keyboard navigation

Tags: css, hover, accessibility

[WCAG 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20130905/C15) recommends to also use `:focus` when `:hover` is used on link elements to support keyboard navigation. This works well for link elements, but there are a couple of differences between the two.

- any element can have the `:hover` state while only very few can be focused
- when hovering over an element, you also hover over all of its parent elements. This is not the case with focus

This question is strictly about css. Is there a way to simulate the behavior of `:hover` (as described above) for keyboard navigation? Or are there any strong reasons why one would not want that?

To make it more clear here is an example:

html:

```
<div id="box">
    foo bar
    <a href="#">click me</a>
</div>
```

css:

```
#box {
    opacity: 0.3;
}
#box:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
#box a:focus {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

When using a mouse I will hover over the link element before using it. Since the `:hover` state propagates upwards `#box` will be fully opaque.

When using a keyboard I will focus the link element before using it. Since the `:focus` state does *not* propagate upwards `#box` will *not* be fully opaque.

Comment: Very interesting.. But I am pretty sure `opacity` just isn't working on `:focus`, and not the other way around. Based on what I know, you can only change a few properties on events such as `:active`/`:focus`/`:visited`.. I could be wrong though.. see http://jsfiddle.net/8G4bY/ ... EDIT... It seems as though `opacity` does work in a few instances.. http://jsfiddle.net/GcxMk/

Comment: [angular-deep-blur](https://github.com/myplanet/angular-deep-blur) is somewhat related. It checks whether the focused element is in the specified subtree and ecentually executes code on every blur event from that subtree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in JavaScript with [focusin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focusin)/[focusout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focusout) events (they are just like `focus` and `blur` except they bubble). [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/t9oq2yxx/1/) is a fiddle.

It boils down to this function:

```
var deepFocus = function(element, cls) {
    cls = cls || 'deep-focus';

    element
        .on('focusin', function() {
            element.addClass(cls);
        })
        .on('focusout', function() {
            var value = !!element.find(':focus').length;
            element.toggleClass(cls, value);
        });
};
```

**Update**: There is a draft spec that contains the [`:focus-within`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) selector which would exactly do what is required here.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of time has past since the original question. Today we have `:focus-within` which should work nicely for cases like this one:

```
#box {
    opacity: 0.3;
}
#box:hover,
#box:focus-within {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make :focus effect on elemnts not link and form elements you need use in tabindex attributes. when you put it on each element you can assign it the :focus pesudo element.

in your example you need understand that opacity is stay on the parent div also if the link opacity change.

you can see working sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xJLAw/). or sample to use tabindex

```
<div tabindex="1">Touch the Div</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Still I hope for an answer to the second part of my question.

Comment: Try to explain me again your second part

Comment: when hovering over an element, you also hover over all of its parent elements. This is not the case with focus. Is there any way to simulate the hover behavior for focus?